# display: table-cell is not behaving like an actual table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I'm trying to build bootstraps new "input-groups". They're using table-cells for input fields and their labels/buttons so that they take up 100% width together.

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

button, input {
    border: 0;
    display: table-cell;   
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

But sadly, the button breaks into a new line, or - if `white-space: nowrap` is used, it's outside of the `.outer`-div.

Here's a JSfiddle that works with tables, but not with other elements that should act as tables:
http://jsfiddle.net/t34Au/1/

Here's the section in bootstrap 3
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The specific problem is that you're giving the input `width: 100%`, and so there's no place for the button. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/t34Au/2/) fiddle

Comment: @Itay: No, that's not really it. That demo is not an accurate representation of his actual problem, since he's using Bootstrap.

Comment: @thirtydot The specific problem in the fiddle was solved when the input's width has changed...

Comment: @Itay: Yeah, it really wasn't solved.

Comment: The problem was not the width and the demo is accurate as i'm **not** using Bootstrap. Bootstrap just serves as an example of what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give `button`s or `input`s that are buttons `display: table-cell`.

It doesn't really work.

If you read http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons it states:

> Buttons in input groups are a bit different and require one extra
>   level of nesting. Instead of `.input-group-addon`, you'll need to use
>   `.input-group-btn` to wrap the buttons. This is required due to default
>   browser styles that cannot be overridden.

Here's a demo showing how to do this without Bootstrap, if you need it: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/t34Au/3/

This uses the same basic method as Bootstrap.

And here's a demo where I copied the HTML from the Bootstrap demo and imported Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/2cGaG/